# What causes 'Recovery completed for database ...' log messages?

Tags: sql-server, recovery

I am running an MS SQL Server Express (64-bit v11.0.2100.60) database and now and then I get problems that my connections times out when I want to connect. In the server log I can see that at that time there are log messages 'Recovery completed for database ...'.

I did not run any datababase recovery nor was anything happened at that time (Windows event  log and MS SQL server logs are both 'clean').

[image: SQL Serverlogs]

What could cause this recovery? Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: It might be related to auto close

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the database options for AutoClose. It looks like your database is having to start up every time someone connects to it after there have been no connections. To start a database, it also involves looking for any non-checkpointed transactions in the log, which then does a recovery to get the database ready for action.

AutoClose should be OFF.

Comment: So the database can be automatically closed in some sort of a 'error' state and then it needs to recover once it starts-up? I find it hard to believe that this is normal. Besides this does not happen every time, just occasionally.

Comment: If AUTO CLOSE of on, it works a *bit different* in express edition. As a fact it can lead to 2-3 minutes of standstill for you database. This article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2008/02/22/sql-express-behaviors-idle-time-resources-usage-auto-close-and-user-instances.aspx would tell you more about what auto clode can do in express edition

Comment: If auto close is false and still you get this message I guess the message would be during server startup or some manual recovery performed

Comment: @dcarapic - not so much an error state, just with part of the transaction log that hasn't been checkpointed into the MDF file. But based on Shanky's response, you might not be able to stop SQL express from doing it.

Comment: I'm going the turn off AutoClose and hopefully the problem should not appear any more. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Cool. Let us know...